# Eliminar comillas de un String java

Tags: java, string

Estoy tratando de conseguir lo siguiente en un `String`:

Entrada:

```
String cadena= " \"esto es \'\' una \"\" prueba\" "
```

Salida

```
String cadena= "esto es \' una \" prueba"
```

He probado con `replaceAll("\"", " ")` pero elimina en las comillas dobles tanto las externas como las internas

Comment: No queda claro cual es la salida esperada. Deberías explicarlo mejor, porque resulta ambiguo.

Comment: La cadena de entrada es el string que se le pasa y esta comprendido entre comillas simples o dobles , y la cadena de salida es el resultado que se pretende conseguir

Comment: Sí estimado, pero cuál es el proceso que quieres que se haga sobre la cadena de entrada para que devuelva la cadena final? A eso me refería con explicar el problema. Si te digo que mi cadena es `$#$#@$@#@#$##@` y quiero una salida de `$#@$@#@##@` entenderías qué hay que hacer? (removí los substrings `#$`). Veo en tu cadena de entrada cuatro `"` y en la salida, solo uno. Y francamente no comprendo qué deseas hacer.

Comment: He modificado la entrada y salida para que se vea mejor

Comment: Prueba con estas dos sentencias: `cadena = cadena.replaceAll("\'\'", "\'");` y  `cadena = cadena.replaceAll("\"\"","\"");`. Esto deberías realizarlo después de haber quitado las comillas situadas al inicio y al final.

Comment: Eso habían escrito antes pero la cosa es quitar también las comillas del principio y final, es lo que no termino de ver

Comment: Vale acabo de ver el método `deleteCharAt()`

Answer (score 1):

A ver si te entiendo

Tratas de eliminar las comillas dobles y simples del String con replaceAll, pero los String no se pueden cambiar, por lo que tendrías que sustituirlo, o sea, crear una nueva cadena de texto, para ello deberías de usar:

```
String texto = "esto es '' una \"\" prueba";
```

Para eliminar las comillas simples:

```
texto = texto.replaceAll("'", "");
```

Para eliminar las comillas dobles:

```
texto = texto.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Sin saber el contexto del que obtienes el String o si lo escribes tu mismo, si es por reescribir un String con el formato que deseas, sería:

```
texto = "\"Esto es ' una \" prueba\"";
```

O sin comillas iniciales y finales:

```
texto = "Esto es ' una \" prueba";
```

Comment: Creo que no es lo que quiere, solamente quiere eliminar las primeras coincidencias

Comment: Quizás tengas razón Eduardo Jiménez, pero como mencionaba TomuRain, no lo deja del todo claro al poner la salida, si es la que pretende o la que él obtiene.

En todo caso, a falta de confirmación dejo la respuesta y no es lo que busca, la elimino. Gracias

Comment: Con que la modifiques, no es necesario eliminarla :)

Habrá que esperar a que clarifique bien la pregunta

Comment: Simplemente es eliminar las comillas situadas al inicio y final de la cadena, y después dentro de la cadena cambiar las dobles apariciones por una sola aparición. La cadena salida es la que pretende

Comment: para eso puedes hacerlo sin regex

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes realizar con un doble "replace" de esta forma:

```
    String cadena= " \"esto es \'\' una \"\" prueba\" ";

    //Elimina espacios en los extremos de la cadena.
    cadena = cadena.trim();
    //Elimina primer comilla doble.
    if(cadena.startsWith("\"")){
        cadena = cadena.substring(1, cadena.length());
    }
    //Elimina ultima comilla doble 
    if(cadena.endsWith("\"")){
        cadena = cadena.substring(0,cadena.length()-1);
    }
    //Reemplaza dobles apariciones por solo una.
    String resultado = cadena.replace("\'\'","\'").replace("\"\"","\"");
    System.out.println(resultado);
```

Tendrìas como salida:

```
   esto es ' una " prueba
```

Comment: Ese caso funciona si quieres cambiar las dobles aparaciones por una sola aparición, además de eso también trato de eliminar las comillas situadas al principio y final de la cadena

Comment: Debes agregar este tipo de información en tu pregunta para saber exactamente que requieres realizar, he agregado una edición a mi respuesta, comenta si funciona, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes encadenar expresiones regulares:

```
    String x = cadena.replaceFirst("^ *\"", "") // Comilla doble al inicio
                     .replaceFirst("\" *$", "") // Comilla doble al final
                     .replaceAll("''", "'")     // Doble Comilla sencilla
                     .replaceAll("\"\"", "\"")  // Doble Comilla doble
                     ;
```